# React Native Windows installation - could not find react-native-windows@0.41.*

Tags: wpf, windows, react-native, uwp

I'm starting to learn React Native, and found out that React Native development can be done on Windows also (thanks to UWP). And, I find this blog (https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-for-windows-ba23a4be90b6#.c117cuwmy) which details the steps on how to install and create React Native project and configure for Windows development. I'm running Windows 10 and have already set developer features to Developer mode under Settings. However, when I tried to initialize windows (run react-native windows), I got an error saying "Could not find react-native-windows@0.41.. Latest version of react-native-windows is 0.40.0-rc.1, try switching to react-native@0.40.." (see screen capture below)

I changed react-native dependencies in package.json under my project folder to 0.39.1 (as mentioned in the blog), but still it doesn't work.

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "0.41.2"
},
```

This is the structure inside package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyFirstProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2",
    "rnpm-plugin-windows": "^0.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The CLI windows plugin is at rnpm-plugin-windows@0.2.3

[image]

Did I miss an important step which caused this error? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let me say that React Native Windows also supports WPF+.NET 4.6 so you can also deploy to Windows 7 and 8.1 with the same 90+% code sharing you get between other React Native platforms.

As mentioned in the React Native Windows FAQ, you can get past this particular error by specifying an older version of react-native when creating your project:

```
react-native windows --windowsVersion 0.40.0-rc.1
```

React Native Windows generally keeps up with upstream releases, but sometimes it can take a few days to catch up. This workaround allows you to get started and then update later.

Comment: Thank you, the workaround works like charm.  I was now able to initialize windows for react native.

Comment: Thank you! I read "also supports" as "only supports WPF"... Yay UWP

Answer (score 1):

@MattHargett is correct, but at least for me, I had to be a little more specific in order to get 0.57 installed. Perhaps the syntax isn't quite up to date...

For me, I had to:

```
react-native windows --windowsVersion react-native-windows@0.57
```